# Does the late 2013 Retina Macbook Pro Support PCI-E SSDs?

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, macos

I'd like to upgrade my late 2013 retina Macbook Pro with a M.2 PCI-E SSD. Is this possible? Do I need an adapter?

Answer (score 6):

As you can see in the image below from [ifixit](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Retina+Display+Late+2013+SSD+Replacement/26811), the 2013 Retina Macbook Pro does have a kind of M.2 PCI-E SSD. (It is the black rectangle the person is holding.)

[image]

However Apple uses proprietary firmware on those SSDs, so only SPECIFICALLY Mac compatible drives will work such as these [these](https://www.ifixit.com/Store/Parts/MacBook-Pro-13-Inch-and-15-Inch-Retina-Late-2013-Mid-2014-SSD/IF123-026-5) and [these](https://eshop.macsales.com/shop/ssd/owc/macbook-pro-retina-display/2013-2014-2015).

This Ifixit [guide](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Retina+Display+Late+2013+SSD+Replacement/26811) shows you how to install a new drive, and links to a page that lets you purchase a compatible drive.

Comment: +1 This is a good answer. Not only does it answer the question, it also provides additional background and explains why it would be pointless upgrading to a M.2 SSD.